# Add roles to loged user from external service using Spring Security and JWT authentication

Tags: spring-security, jwt, roles

Our application use third party system to authenticate users. Having JWT token, UI calls the API server. The problem is that the JWT do not contains user roles. To fix that our
Java backend needs to call another external system and organise authorisation - very slow, buggy and verbose.

Is there a way with **Java Spring Security** to handle this situation?

1. We can't rewrite JWT, so this is not an option.
2. Can we add roles in Security context and use it as cache? Not optimal but progress.
3. Is it acceptable to organise "second" login to the backend system and send to the UI
   another JWT with roles? The problem with the different time of expiration exist ...
4. Are there any customisers, filters that could be used?
5. Is the [JwtAuthenticationConverter](https://github.com/Basit-Mahmood/spring-authorization-server-password-grant-type-support/blob/d8df884e4feadc4877a9e74d16f3dc49f7c63e2c/SpringResourceServer/src/main/java/pk/training/basit/configuration/ResourceServerConfiguration.java#L30) suitable?

Any kind of help is welcome: ideas, suggestions, links, articles or books.
Thank you in advance

Comment: i think 5 is appropriate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to write you own [UserDetailsService](https://github.com/louisthomas/cloud-security-workshop/blob/60effb4a1c0914f59a796bc65c3c4cd208cbaa89/solution/product/src/main/java/com/example/security/ProductUserDetailsService.java). This is a standard approach to add additional information. Then [converter](https://github.com/louisthomas/cloud-security-workshop/blob/60effb4a1c0914f59a796bc65c3c4cd208cbaa89/solution/product/src/main/java/com/example/security/ProductJwtAuthenticationConverter.java) will create a token with enriched user information.

The example project could be found [here](https://github.com/louisthomas/cloud-security-workshop/tree/60effb4a1c0914f59a796bc65c3c4cd208cbaa89/solution/product/src/main/java/com/example) and its [explanation](https://andifalk.gitbook.io/oauth-2.1-and-openid-connect-for-java-developers/hands-on-labs/product#step-5-convert-the-jwt-into-the-productuser-object)

In my case I needed to communicate with the external system using OAuth. Guide how to configure it is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-feign-oauth-token).

Comment: This answer is faulty, as a JWT should not be used as a session token. And userdetailsservice is used with session authentication. Tokens should not be passed to browsers as oauth2 has deprecated the implicit flow. So dont follow this advice.

Comment: Follow my links and decide yourself. Just to mention that the AuthenticationProvider uses UserDetailsService for retrieving user information from a backend data source, such as a database or an external service. UserDetailsService is NOT used with session authentication. UserDetailsService is common part of the Spring Security model.

Comment: I know exactly what it is used for. JWTs should not be used for session based authentication as i pointed out as the implicit flow has been deprecated. The whole purpose of using a JWT is to avoid having to do external database lookups or intrespection calls. So once again the answer is just a complete antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer here is quite simple, use the JWT correcly and make sure that whatever scopes/roles are included into the signed JWT.**

If this can't be done, then the entire JWT "solution" should be removed as it doesn't fit the security model.

I will ignore the fact that the question asker is laying out ground rules of what can or can not be done. Because the question basically asks us "how can i store items in a sequential collection, but it can not be a list". The question makes no sense, and the solution is crystal clear.